# How to turn on/activate openssl exention for php 5.4?

Tags: php, openssl

Linux Debian 10. Native php - v.7.3. Some alternative php: 7.4, 7.2, 5.4.45.
Openssl extension for php is installed:

```
root@myserver:~# whereis openssl
openssl: /usr/bin/openssl /usr/include/openssl /usr/share/man/man1/openssl.1ssl.gz
```

It is acceptable for all php versions: 5.6.40 and above (7.0, 7.1, 7.4). But for php 5.4.45 openssl is out of use :(

How to install/turn on/activate openssl for php 5.4.45?